# Arrays of primitive data types vs. primitive data type manipulation

Tags: java, arrays, types, primitive

How come this

```
int[] a = {0, 1};
int[] b = a;
a[0] = 1;
b[0] = 2;
System.out.println(a[0] + b[0]);
```

prints 4 and this

```
int a = 2;
int b = a;
b += 3;
System.out.println(a);
```

prints 2.

Is it something to do with how arrays are using byReference and can manipulate the original value while pure primitive operations use byValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` is a primitive, not an object, so it just contains a value. When you assign one primitive to another (`a = b`), you are simply giving the first the same value as the second. So when you change the second it has no effect on the first.

`int[]` is an array, which is an object, as are all the elements of the array. That means they're actually pointing to a place in the memory. When you assign one object to another(`a[0] = b[0]` or even `a = b` when `a` and `b` are arrays), you're pointing them both to the same place in the memory. So when you change the second it also changes the first because they're actually pointing to the same thing.

If you want `b[0]` to only contain the *value* of `a[0]` you could do this:

```
    int[] a = {1, 2};
    int [] b = new int[2];
    b[0] = Arrays.copyOf(a,1)[0];
```

In other words, the 0th element of a new array made when you copy only the first element of a.

Update: You could also just run it through a primitive, like this:

```
int x = a[0];
b[0] = x;
```

Which now that I think of it is probably more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is straightforward, as both arrays `a` and `b` point to the same object in memory, changing one will affect the other. In other words when you perform `b = a;`, you're essentially copying the *reference* from `a` and storing it into `b`, meaning both `a` & `b` hold a *reference* to the array.

The second example you're basically copying the *value* of variable `a` and storing it into `b`, there is **no** relationship between `a` and `b`, changing one will **not** affect the other.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, an array variable is an Object Reference.

`{0, 1}` is shorthand syntax for creating an array with the given values. The following are all the same:

```
int[] a = {0, 1};

int[] a = new int[] {0, 1};

int[] a = new int[2];
a[0] = 0;
a[1] = 1;
```

So, when you write `b = a;`, the `b` variable is assigned the same reference value as the `a` variable, i.e. it references the same array. Therefore, `a[0]` and `b[0]` references the same value.

Said another way: An array variable stores a reference to the array. It doesn't store the array itself, so `b = a;` *doesn't* copy the array.